# How to slice a 2D Python Array? Fails with: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Tags: python, multidimensional-array, numpy

I have a 2d array in the numpy module that looks like:

```
data = array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])
```

I want to get a slice of this array that only includes certain columns of element.  For example I may want columns 0 and 2:

```
data = [[1,3],
        [4,6],
        [7,9]]
```

What is the most Pythonic way to do this?  (No for loops please)

I thought this would work:

```
newArray = data[:,[0,2]]
```

but it results in a:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

Comment: Downvote. This cannot be reproduced in 2021. `NameError: name 'array' is not defined`. At least "today", the question is plain wrong, and I doubt it was different in 2010.

Answer (score 17):

The error say it explicitely : data is not a numpy array but a  list of lists.

try to convert it to an numpy array first :

```
numpy.array(data)[:,[0,2]]
```

Comment: Nice catch!  I bow to your psychic debugging abilities! :)

Answer (score 11):

If you'd want to slice 2D **list** the following function may help

```
def get_2d_list_slice(self, matrix, start_row, end_row, start_col, end_col):
    return [row[start_col:end_col] for row in matrix[start_row:end_row]]
```

Comment: Great! Good coding here! Should not that the start of 0

Answer (score 5):

Actually, what you wrote should work just fine... What version of numpy are you using?

Just to verify, the following should work perfectly with any recent version of numpy:

```
import numpy as np
x = np.arange(9).reshape((3,3)) + 1
print x[:,[0,2]]
```

Which, for me, yields:

```
array([[1, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [7, 9]])
```

as it should...

Comment: The example of the question does not "work just fine". Yours works because you create a np array from the scratch, the OP just copied the numpy output. In 2010 or now, the behaviour should be the same.

Answer (score 4):

THis may not be what you are looking for but this is would do.
zip(*x)[whatever columns you might need]

Answer (score 2):

**Why it works on Numpy but not Python lists**

Because with `__getitem__` you can program you classes to do whatever you want with `:` and multiple arguments.

Numpy does this, but built-in `list`s do not.

More precisely:

```
class C(object):
    def __getitem__(self, k):
        return k

# Single argument is passed directly.
assert C()[0] == 0

# Multiple indices generate a tuple.
assert C()[0, 1] == (0, 1)

# Slice notation generates a slice object.
assert C()[1:2:3] == slice(1, 2, 3)

# If you omit any part of the slice notation, it becomes None.
assert C()[:] == slice(None, None, None)
assert C()[::] == slice(None, None, None)
assert C()[1::] == slice(1, None, None)
assert C()[:2:] == slice(None, 2, None)
assert C()[::3] == slice(None, None, 3)

# Tuple with a slice object:
assert C()[:, 1] == (slice(None, None, None), 1)

# Ellipsis class object.
assert C()[...] == Ellipsis
```

We can then open up slice objects as:

```
s = slice(1, 2, 3)
assert s.start == 1
assert s.stop == 2
assert s.step == 3
```

So that is why when you write:

```
[][1, 2]
```

Python says:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple
```

because you are trying to pass `(1, 2)` to the list's `__getitem__`, and built-in lists are not programmed to deal with tuple arguments, only integers.

Answer (score 1):

Beware that numpy only accept regular array with the same size for each elements. 
you can somehow use :
`[a[i][0:2] for i in xrange(len(a))]`
it's pretty ugly but it works.

Comment: Numpy accepts any combination of slices, integers and arrays. The arrays do not have to be the same size, but they should broadcast against each other. And I believe the expression you looking for is `[[row[0], row[2]] for row in data]`.

Answer (score 0):

```
newArray = data[:,0:2]
```

or am I missing something?

Answer (score 0):

The example in question begins with `array`, not with `np.array`, and `array` is not defined as an isolated prefix:

```
data = array([[1,2,3],
              [4,5,6],
              [7,8,9]])

data[:,[0,2]]
```

Error:

```
NameError: name 'array' is not defined
```

To reproduce the error, you need to drop that `array` frame (without `np.` in front, it does not have a definition anyway).

```
data = [[1,2,3],
        [4,5,6],
        [7,8,9]]

data[:,[0,2]]
```

Error:

```
TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple
```

The user has probably used the inner list of the array for tests but asked the question with a copy from a `np.array` output. At least in 2021, the question is just plain wrong: it cannot be reproduced. And I doubt that the behaviour was different in 2010 (numpy is *the* basic package of python).

For completeness, as in the other answers:

```
data = np.array([[1,2,3],
                [4,5,6],
                [7,8,9]])

data[:,[0,2]]
```

Output:

```
array([[1, 3],
       [4, 6],
       [7, 9]])
```

---

You do not need a nested list to reproduce this. Slicing a one-dimensional list by two dimensions like with

```
[1,2][:, 0]
```

throws the same `TypeError: list indices must be integers or slices, not tuple`.