# Python: "TypeError: list indices must be integers, not tuple"

Tags: python, numpy

I have a dataset read from a `.csv` file which is a 2d array.
 Now I want to slice the dataset and get the first element of every list in it.

```
import numpy as np

rawData = []
with open(path) as file:
    lines = csv.reader(file)
    for line in lines:
        rawData.append(line)

dataSet = rawData[0:10] # as the whole dataset is too large, I get the first ten rows to test
np.array(dataSet)
labels = dataSet[:,0]
```

If I run:

```
print np.shape(dataSet)
>>>(10, 785)
```

I've referred [How to slice a 2D Python Array](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680262/how-to-slice-a-2d-python-array-fails-with-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-int). However I still got this error.

Comment: `np.array(dataSet)` isn't being assigned, you're creating an array then immediately abandoning it.

Comment: Nice catch! Solved it!

Comment: So perhaps add an answer as a community wiki entry. Or simply delete the question now your problem is solved?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @jonrsharpe .
`np.array(dataSet)` just create a new numpy array but I didn't assign it to `dataSet`.
It should be

```
result = np.array(dataSet)
```

Comment: It's not advisable to use the same variables for different values, you should use a new variable for that.

Answer (score 1):

Syntax is wrong in the line: `labels = dataSet[:,0]`.

In your code `dataSet` is a python list and you are trying to access its key by using a python tuple `,0`; the comma defines a tuple in python.
You should use integers as the error message suggests.

To solve this, convert `dataSet` to a numpy array like this: `numpy.array(dataSet)`.