# Python Openpyxl, copy and paste cell range

Tags: python, excel, openpyxl

I know how to select a cell range in Openpyxl:

```
cell_range = sheet['A1':'C3']
```

How can I paste cell_range above to another range, like `sheet['A11':'C13']`?

Comment: AFAIK you can't copy specific cells but I could be wrong. I think it's possible to copy an entire worksheet though.

Answer (score 3):

I don't think there is a slicing notation exactly as described in your example, mostly because `openpyxl` uses lists of `Cell`s rather than lists of plain values.

Here is the basic flow I would use to grab just a part of a sheet.

```
>>> wb = openpyxl.load_workbook(file_name)
>>> sheet = wb.worksheets[0]
>>> rows = sheet.rows[1:3]                                      # slice rows
>>> foobar = [cell.value for row in rows for cell in row[3:10]] # slice row
```

***EDIT:***  From [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3680262/how-to-slice-a-2d-python-array-fails-with-typeerror-list-indices-must-be-int) it looks like you can do something like this:

```
foo = [row[start_col:end_col] for row in sheet.rows[start_row:end_row]]
```

Which will give you a list of lists *of cells*.  Remember to use `foo[i][j].value` to get the contents of a `cell`.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look at [this snippet](https://bitbucket.org/snippets/openpyxl/qyzKn) for some ideas. Please note it is **entirely** unsupported.